# How to inject specific property value while Json deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

I need to inject the specific property value to object that is being deserialize using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method.

for example I have a class

```
public class Employee
{
   public int EmployeeID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int OrgnizationID {get; set;}
}
```

Json

```
[
    {
      "employeeID": 1,
      "name": "Neeraj"
    },
    {
      "employeeID": 2,
      "name": "Sam"
    },
    {
      "employeeID": 3,
      "name": "Jonson"
    } 
]
```

above json string converting to list of employee. Here I am looking a way to set the `OrgnizationID` with some value for full of list. I know I can set it after conversion, but god to have if I can set it along with conversion.

```
var employees  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonData);
```

in above line of code I am also passing the JsonSerializerSettings for some other purpose that not defined here just to keep question simple.

Comment: Is it a constant value that never changes ? Well you have 3 options how you could set it - field/property initializer, default constructor or after Deserialization

Comment: @Fabjan, its not a constant, can vary